# node.js 404 file not found error

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, couchbase-nodejs-sdk

```
var http = require('http'),
fs=require('fs'),
path=require('path'),
host ='127.0.0.1',
port='9001';
var mimes = {
    ".htm":"text/html",
    ".css":"text/css",
    ".js":"text/javascript",
    ".gif":"text/gif",
    ".jpg":"text/jpeg",
    ".png":"text/png"
}
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    var filepath =(req.url==='/')?('./index.htm'):('.'+req.url);
    var contentType = mimes[path.extname(filepath)];
    //check file exists or not
    fs.exists(filepath,function(file_exists){
        if(file_exists)
        {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : contentType});
                var streamFile = fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(res);
                streamFile.on('error',function(){
                    res.writeHead(500);
                    res.end();
                })
        }
        else
        {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end("sorry we could not find the file you requested");
        }
    })
}).listen(port,host,function(){
console.log('server running on http://'+host+':'+port);
})
```

In the above code my node server is giving message its runs in 127.0.0.1:9001, but when I run it in my browser I face "error 404 file not found", which is not the error I mentioned. Also I have index.html file inside the same folder of this script file. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works fine for me.
You should have `index.htm` file in the same folder you execute the `server.js` file.

Change the if condition

```
index.html != index.htm
```

Answer (score 2):

**Actually your code work fine,**

*you may change your 404*

```
  res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  res.end("sorry we could not find the file you requested");
```

Also see we have set the response type to 'text/html'

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,but I don't know why its not reading my static index.html file .